# Upper bound for $(1-1/x)^x$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

I remember the bound $$\left(1-\frac1x\right)^x\leq e^{-1}$$ but I can't recall under which condition it holds, or how to prove it. Does it hold for all $x>0$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting from $e^x \geq 1+x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$:

For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$
$$ e^{-x} \geq 1-x. $$
For all $x \neq 0$
$$ e^{-1/x} \geq 1-\frac{1}{x}. $$
And, since $t \mapsto t^x$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$, for $x \geq 1$
$$ e^{-1} \geq \left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x. $$

Comment: But $t \mapsto t^x$ is increasing only for $t>1$ or $t<-1$ for $x \geq 1$?

Comment: @user1105 Here the statement that the function f(t) = t^x is increasing means that if t <= u then f(t) <= f(u).  It doesn't mean f(t) >= t.

Answer (score 3):

Bernoulli's Inequality says that
$$
1+nt\le\left(1+t\right)^n\tag{1}
$$
for all $t\ge-1$ and $n\ge1$. Thus, if $y\ge x\ge1$,
$$
\begin{align}
1-\frac1x
&=1-\frac yx\frac1y\\
&\le\left(1-\frac1y\right)^{y/x}\\
\left(1-\frac1x\right)^x
&\le\left(1-\frac1y\right)^y\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
We can send $y\to\infty$ to get
$$
\left(1-\frac1x\right)^x
\le\frac1e\tag{3}
$$
for $x\ge1$.