# Upper bound for product of exponents

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, exponential-function

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544667/upper-bound-for-1-1-xx) we have the bound

> $$\left(1-\frac1N\right)^N\leq e^{-1}$$
>
> where $N$ is a positive integer.

Written another way, it is

> $$\left(1-\frac1{N_1}\right)^{k_1}\left(1-\frac1{N_2}\right)^{k_2}\ldots \left(1-\frac1{N_r}\right)^{k_r}\leq e^{-1}$$ where $N_1=N_2=\ldots=N_r=N$ and $\dfrac{k_1}{N_1}+\dfrac{k_2}{N_2}+\ldots+\dfrac{k_r}{N_r}=1$.

Is it true in general that

> $$\left(1-\frac1{N_1}\right)^{k_1}\left(1-\frac1{N_2}\right)^{k_2}\ldots \left(1-\frac1{N_r}\right)^{k_r}\leq e^{-1}$$

for positive integers $N_1,N_2,\ldots N_r,k_1,k_2,\ldots k_r$ such that $\dfrac{k_1}{N_1}+\dfrac{k_2}{N_2}+\ldots+\dfrac{k_r}{N_r}=1$? If not, what upper bound can we find for the left-hand expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In full generality, for every nonnegative $n$ and every $a\lt1$, 
$$\left(1-a\right)^n\leqslant\mathrm e^{-an}.
$$
Using this for $a=1/N_i$ and $n=k_i$ yields $\left(1-1/N_i\right)^{k_i}\leqslant\mathrm e^{-k_i/N_i}$ hence
$$
\prod_i\left(1-\frac1{N_i}\right)^{k_i}\leqslant\exp\left(-\sum_i\frac{k_i}{N_i}\right).
$$

Answer (score 3):

I think I just got it. Following the proof in the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544667/upper-bound-for-1-1-xx):

$$\left(1-\dfrac{1}{N_1}\right)\leq e^{-1/N_1}$$

so $$\left(1-\dfrac{1}{N_1}\right)^{k_1}\leq e^{-k_1/N_1}$$

Therefore, $$\left(1-\frac1{N_1}\right)^{k_1}\left(1-\frac1{N_2}\right)^{k_2}\ldots \left(1-\frac1{N_r}\right)^{k_r}\leq e^{-(k_1/N_1+k_2/N_2+\ldots+k_r/N_r)}=e^{-1}.$$