# Bernoulli trials: Probability of $\lim\sup A_n$ depending on $p$

Tags: probability-theory

We have an infinite sequence of Bernoulli's trials with $p$ being the probability of success. Let $A_n$ the next event: in trials under numbers from $2^n$ to $2^{n+1}-1$ there were at least $n$ successes in row.

I have to find the probability of the $\lim\sup A_n$ depending on $p$.

I already estimated that
$$
P(A_n)<(2^n)p^n,
$$ thus for $p<\frac{1}{2}$ we have $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)<\infty$$ which means (Borel–Cantelli lemma) $$ P(\lim\sup A_n)=0.$$

I found that the answer for $p\ge\frac{1}{2}$ is that we should have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)=\infty$$ because of $$P(A_n)\ge1-e^{\frac{(2p)^n}{2n}}.$$ Could someone explain why is it like that? I honestly have no idea where did *e* come from.

Comment: Do you mean that $A_n$ is the next event:  in trials from $2^n$ to $2^{n+1}-1$ there are at least $n$ successes in a row (or  not less than $n$)?
The notation $p<\frac{1}{2} \lim supA_n<\infty$ is not correct: we can't compare probabilities and events. Also we can't write that $\lim supA_n=\infty$ by the same reason.

Comment: @BotnakovN. thanks, I edited the question, I forgot about space between probability and an event. When it comes to A_n, I actually don't know, the exercise says "n successes one after the other" so I can only assume they meant "at least n successes in a row"

Comment: Sahoto, you wrote that $\limsup A_n = \infty$, but $\limsup A_n$ is an event, it is a subset of $\Omega$ and can't be equal to $\infty$.

Comment: @BotnakovN. Right, I meant sum of probabilites

Comment: @Sahoto, Hi, if I may ask, what book are you using to study Probability theory?

Comment: @Quasar unfortunately, this book isn't available in English: Wstęp do teorii prawdopodobieństwa - J. Jakubowski, R. Sztencel

Comment: Thanks for sharing though, I am based out of Poland, so I should definitely make an attempt to learn some Polish!

Comment: This link may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544667/upper-bound-for-1-1-xx [possibly using it with chopping the $2^n$ trials into disjoint groups of size $n$, there being approximately $2^n/n$ such groups, or a bound on that might be $2^n/(2n)$.]

Comment: @Michael Thank for the link, now I can see where that came from. But why 2n, not n?

Comment: There are $\lfloor 2^n/n\rfloor$ groups, and a coarse lower bound on that is $2^n/(2n)$. I was just trying to reverse-engineer the bound you gave and get that extra factor of 2 that appears.  Maybe I didn't do the computation carefully enough and a factor of 2 arises for some other reason.